# Android + Xamarin push notification custom sound will not play

Tags: android, xamarin, notifications, push

I've been working with the simple concept of playing a custom sound in my Android Xamarin app, but no matter what I try the sound will not play.

I have created a "raw" folder under Resources, and added an appropriate sound file.  I have made sure that file is being built as an Android resource.

Here's my code:

```
// note I have also tried just /raw/NotificationSound, /integeridofresource and many other formats
string sSoundUrl = "android.resource://" + AppGlobals.PackageName + "/raw/NotificationSound.wav";

Notification nNotification = new Notification.Builder(this.Activity).SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.AppIcon)
                .SetContentTitle("Test title")
                .SetContentText("Hello notifications")
                .SetAutoCancel(true)
                .SetSound(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(sSoundUrl)).Build();

// I have tried 0, All, NotificationDefaults.Sound basically all different  combinations
nNotification.Defaults = NotificationDefaults.Lights;

NotificationManager nmNotManager = (NotificationManager)this.Activity.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);

nmNotManager.Notify(0, nNotification);
```

I'm hoping somebody can spot what I'm doing wrong...

Thanks!!!

Comment: Is this code in a class that derives from `GcmListenerService`?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are close, there are just a few subtle differences between your code and what we have working in several Xamarin.Android apps.

I believe the salient differences are that we use the `GcmListenerService`-derived class as the context rather than `this.Activity`, we omit the ".wav" extension in the path, we generate a unique-ish id for the notification, and we set an intent.

Here is some code that shows the approach:

```
        var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.PutExtra(MainActivity.GoToAction, action);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
        var pushId = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Milliseconds;
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, pushId, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        // Set custom push notification sound.
        var pathToPushSound = "android.resource://" + context.ApplicationContext.PackageName + "/raw/pushalert";
        var soundUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(pathToPushSound);

        var notificationBuilder = new Android.App.Notification.Builder(context)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon_transparent)
            .SetContentTitle(title)
            .SetContentText(message)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetSound(soundUri)
            .SetStyle(new Android.App.Notification.BigTextStyle().BigText(message))
            .SetVibrate(new long[] {100, 1000, 100})
            .SetLights(Android.Resource.Color.HoloOrangeDark, 1, 1)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
        notificationManager.Notify(pushId, notificationBuilder.Build());
```

Comment: thanks for the ideas!  I used your recommendations, unfortunately still no luck...  I'm really running out of ideas...

Comment: Update: After trying this with a default ringtone it works, so it has to be the way I'm referencing the sound.  Just not sure what I'm doing wrong...  Pathing seems pretty basic and I've checked it over and over again.

Comment: @JamesScott Did you try the sound file path without filetype specified?

Comment: yes, I've tried it with /raw/resourcename, /resourceid, /resourcename.wav...  None of them work.  Interestingly when I create a MediaPlayer object and point it at the raw resource it plays just fine...  The other thing that is strange is it just plays my default Samsung notification tone when I call NotificationManager.Notify

Comment: Well I think I finally figured it out.  If you are having trouble with your sounds I would recommend:

1) Create a Media Player object like I did and see if it can play your Uri
2) Check to make sure you have the right defaults set for the Notification object.  In my case I set Defaults to 0 and it played the sound...

Comment: @JamesScott I guess you should post answer with that change to the line where you had originally set `Defaults` to exclude sounds. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Well I think I finally figured it out. If you are having trouble with your sounds I would recommend: 1) Create a Media Player object like I did and see if it can play your Uri 2) Check to make sure you have the right defaults set for the Notification object. In my case I set Defaults to 0 and it played the sound...

Comment: facing same problem as yours. can you share your code?

Comment: @Joker_37 I didn't see your comment until now.  Sorry!  If you still want code let me know I'll post what I've got.